# Subsetting A Pytorch Tensor Using Square-Brackets

Tags: python, pytorch

I came across a line of code used to reduce a 3D Tensor to a 2D Tensor in PyTorch. The 3D tensor `x` is of size `torch.Size([500, 50, 1])` and this line of code:

`x = x[lengths - 1, range(len(lengths))]`

was used to reduce `x` to a 2D tensor of size `torch.Size([50, 1])`. `lengths` is also a tensor of shape `torch.Size([50])` containing values.

Please can anyone explain how this works? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

After being quite stumped by the behavior, I did some more digging into this, and found that it is [consistent behavior with the indexing of multi-dimensional NumPy arrays](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/user/basics.indexing.html#indexing-multi-dimensional-arrays). What makes this counter-intuitive is the less obvious fact that both arrays *have* to have the same length, i.e. in this case `len(lengths)`.

In fact, it works as the following:
 * `lengths` is determining the order in which you access the first dimension. I.e., if you have a 1D array `a = [0, 1, 2, ...., 500]`, and access it with the list `b = [300, 200, 100]`, then the result `a[b] = [301, 201, 101]` (This also explains the `lengths - 1` operator, which simply causes the accessed values to be the same as the index used in `b`, or `lengths`, respectively).
 * `range(len(lengths))` then *simply chooses the `i`-th element in the `i`-th row. If you have a square matrix, you can interpret this as the diagonal of the matrix. Since you only access a single element for each position along the first two dimensions, this can be stored in a single dimension (thus reducing your 3D tensor to 2D). The latter dimension is simply kept "as is".

If you want to play around with this, I strongly recommend to change the `range()` value to something longer/shorter, which will result in the following error:

> IndexError: shape mismatch: indexing arrays could not be broadcast
>   together with shapes (x,) (y,)

where `x` and `y` are your specific length values.

To write this accessing method out in the long form to understand what happens "under the hood", also consider the below example:

```py
import torch
x = torch.randint(500, 50, 1)
lengths = torch.tensor([2, 30, 1, 4])  # random examples to explore
diag = list(range(len(lengths)))  # [0, 1, 2, 3]
result = []
for i, row in enumerate(lengths):
    temp_tensor = x[row, :, :]  # temp_tensor.shape = [1, 50, 1]
    temp_tensor = temp_tensor.squeeze(0)[diag[i]]  # temp_tensor.shape = [1, 1]
    result.append(temp.tensor)

# back to pytorch
result = torch.tensor(result)
result.shape  # [4, 1]
```

Answer (score 2):

The key feature here is passing values of a tensor `lengths` as indices for `x`. 
Here simplified example, I swaped dimensions of container, so index dimenson goes first:

```
container = torch.arange(0, 50 )
container = f.reshape((5, 10))
>>>tensor([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
        [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
        [20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
        [30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39],
        [40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49]])

indices = torch.arange( 2, 7, dtype=torch.long )
>>>tensor([2, 3, 4, 5, 6])

print( container[ range( len(indices) ), indices] )
>>>tensor([ 2, 13, 24, 35, 46])
```

Note: we got one thing from a row ( `range( len(indices) )` makes sequential row numbers), with column number given by indices[ row_number ]